# How do I stop Pandas loosing 1 digit of datetime2 precision?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm reading some SQL Server data into Pandas using the `read_sql_query` function. The problem is I am loosing one digit of precision on `DATETIME2` columns.

Coding exmaple:

```
query = pd.read_sql_query(
'''
    SELECT CAST('2021-05-06 15:44:29.1234567' AS DATETIME2(7)) AS ServiceDate
''', source_engine)

df = pd.DataFrame(query)

df
```

Results:

```
Out[71]: 
0   2021-05-06 15:44:29.123456
```

This does actually cause a problem for data comparisons so I need to ensure the precision is identical.

How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: What is your database connect SQL Server right?

Comment: Correct, SQL Server.